# Javascript timer ends incorrectly

Tags: javascript, html, timer, countdown

Looking for some insight on why my javascript timer doesn't work correctly. Actually it works great except for the fact that it stops with 1 second left and displays an alert. When you hit the ok button it counts down to the final second (0) and displays the alert again. I can't figure out how to stop the alert occuring at 1 second left instead of only at zero seconds...

I altered the code to run at 6 seconds instead of the full ten minutes

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
      alert('Time has exceeded');
      location.href = "http://nova.umuc.edu/~ct388a13/";
    }
  }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var tenMinutes = 60 * .1,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(tenMinutes, display);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p id="transactionTimer">Act fast! This transaction must be completed in <span id="time">10:00</span> minutes</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the JS is exectuted for the DOM update is shown to the user. This has to do with the JS event loop, and can be circumvented by using setTimeout with a very low timeout, ie 1ms. See the code snippet below for a working example

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function() {
    --timer
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
   
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    if (timer === 0) {
      setTimeout(function(){
          alert('Time has exceeded');
          location.href = "http://nova.umuc.edu/~ct388a13/";
      }, 1);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var tenMinutes = 60 * .1,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(tenMinutes, display);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p id="transactionTimer">Act fast! This transaction must be completed in <span id="time">10:00</span> minutes</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Change minutes to seconds.